# Changing name layer from geoprocessing output

Tags: pyqgis, layer-name

How can I change the name for geoprocessing output map layers, for example:

```
out_diss = 'ogr:dbname=\'C:/GIS/data/testdata/output.gpkg\' table=\"ak_riks_dissolved\" (geom)'

dissolved = processing.run("native:dissolve", 
    {'INPUT':'C:/GIS/data/testdata/ak_riks.shp','FIELD':[],
    'OUTPUT':out_diss})['OUTPUT']

dissolved.setTitle('dissolved') #No difference
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(dissolved)
```

Instead of the default very long name:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `QgsVectorLayer` method to change the layer name before adding it to the layer tree:

```
out_diss = 'ogr:dbname=\'C:/GIS/data/testdata/output.gpkg\' table=\"ak_riks_dissolved\" (geom)'

dissolved = processing.run("native:dissolve", 
    {'INPUT':'C:/GIS/data/testdata/ak_riks.shp','FIELD':[],
    'OUTPUT':out_diss})['OUTPUT']

vLayer = QgsVectorLayer(out_diss, "Dissolve", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vLayer)
```

Answer (score 4):

An approach that I mentioned in comments, using [`setName()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#aa6cbb1bf0644d7bb82d410ca56557d6c) method:

```py
out_diss = 'ogr:dbname=\'C:/Temp/output.gpkg\' table=\"ak_riks_dissolved\" (geom)'

layer_input = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("LayerB")[0]

dissolved = processing.run("native:dissolve", 
    {'INPUT':layer_input,
    'FIELD':[],
    'OUTPUT':out_diss})['OUTPUT']
    
dissolved.setName('Renamed!')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(dissolved)
```

---

**References:**

- [PyQGIS 101: Managing project layers](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-managing-project-layers/)

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me. I use the **processing.runAndLoadResults** method to automatically add the layer to the project. The name of my output layer is well "dissolved".

```
int_diss = 'C:/Users/v.bre/Desktop/test_dissolve.shp'
out_diss = 'ogr:dbname=\'C:/Users/v.bre/Desktop/zzz/name/dissolve.gpkg\' table=\"dissolved\" (geom)'

dissolved = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:dissolve", {'INPUT':int_diss,'FIELD':[],'OUTPUT':out_diss})
```

You can also try to use the **setName** method to rename a layer instead of **setTitle**.